# VSCode convert project to 4 spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used the Vue cli to create a project and it uses 2 spaces by default. I want to get 4 spaces. I've turned off detect indentation, set tab size to 4 but no amount of running format document will change - for example - this little js file that was created.

I also tried to change things with eslint. It spots the errors but `--fix` has no effect

If I start a new object then the spaces are correct though.

[image: tabs]

Answer (score 4):

I am using an extension called Vetur and in my VS Code settings file I added the following rule: `"vetur.format.options.tabSize": 4,`

Also for initial indentation I have added the following rules:

`"vetur.format.styleInitialIndent": true,
"vetur.format.scriptInitialIndent": true,`

If you are not using this extension, do you have a `.editorconfig` file in your solution and/or have you looked at your VS Code settings for conflicting rules?

Comment: Also one can create a file on root `.vscode/settings.json` and apply above vetur settings in it like 
`{
    "vetur.format.options.tabSize": 4,
    "vetur.format.styleInitialIndent": true,
    "vetur.format.scriptInitialIndent": true,
}`. This will override for the current project only.